# Prove that a function g which diverges at $\pm\infty$ has interval [a,b] such that if $x\notin[a,b] \implies g(x) > g(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Let $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that  $ \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} = +\infty$. Show that there exists a segment $[a,b]$ with $a < b$ such that $x\notin[a,b] \implies g(x) > g(0)$

---

We prove that [a,b] exists as a direct consequence of the definition of divergence.

Because the limit at $+\infty$ is $+\infty$:
$$
\exists N, \forall x\in\mathbb R, x\ge N\implies  g(x) > g(0)
$$

Similarly, because the limit at $-\infty$ is $+\infty$:
$$
\exists M, \forall x\in\mathbb R, x\le M\implies  g(x) > g(0)
$$

We have thus found an interval $I = [M,N]$, with $M < N$. If $x\notin I$, then $x>N$ or $x<M \implies g(x) > g(0)$.

---

The only part where I feel uncomfortable is stating that $M < N$. We could choose $N_0 = |N|$ and $M_0=-|M|$ and then construct the interval $I = [M_0,N_0]$. It seems to make sense to me that M > N is a contradiction, but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like $M>N$ is a contradiction, if you consider that $0$ must lie in one of the intervals $(-\infty, M]$, $[N, \infty)$ when there's an overlap.  But, it doesn't matter for your proof, because **you get to choose** the values of $a$ and $b$.  So, picking the $M_0$ and $N_0$ as you have works perfectly fine.